# Using lodash, how I can get the maximum length of nested array object

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I need to take the data from below mentioned array of object which has maximum length of nested array object. As per below my request, id : 2 values has 3 objects, result will be as mentioned below.

Anyone help me using lodash or some javascript function to achieve this.

Sample Request:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "values": [
        {
            "sub": "fr",
            "name": "foobar1"
        }, 
        {
            "sub": "en",
            "name": "foobar2"
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "id": 2,
    "values": [
        {
            "sub": "fr",
            "name": "foobar3"
        },
        {
            "sub": "en",
             "name": "foobar4"
        },
        {
                "sub": "ts",
                 "name": "foobar5"
            },
        ]
    }]
```

Expected output:

```
"values": [
        {
            "sub": "fr",
            "name": "foobar3"
        },
        {
            "sub": "en",
             "name": "foobar4"
        },
        {
                "sub": "ts",
                 "name": "foobar5"
            },
        ]
    }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the native javascript `reduce` function as follows

```
var source = [...];
source.reduce((max, cur) => cur.values.length > max.values.length ? cur : max, source[0])
```